# Raw or Mean data; Anova or Regression

Tags: r, regression, anova, mean

I would like to learn what is the correct way to approach analysis of this data. I have done some reading on the subject, but I still feel uncertain. Perhaps many approaches are valid, but simply  that some are more conservative than others?

My study:

I have 5 grasslands, and in each grassland I have 30 spiders. For each spider I have an estimate of what proportion of herbivores it consumes "Diet" (so 5 x 30, n = 150). For each grassland I also have an estimate of the overall biomass of herbivores that exist there "Biomass". Thus I have 5 values of "Biomass" (one for each grassland) and 150 of "Diet" (30 spiders per grassland). Both Diet and Biomass are continous variables.

I would like to run an anlysis that tests how Diet changes across Biomass and derive a slope value, thus keeping Biomass as a continous variable:

Diet ~ Biomass

As I understand it, if I use raw data for Diet (n=150) then using anova is more approrpiate, and grassland becomes a factor with 5 levels.

Or I could run it as a linear regression and thus keep Biomass as a continuous variable and derive a slope value. However, as a linear regression, should I use the raw data (n=150) or mean values (so 5 means - one for each grassland based on 30 samples). Which of the 2 linear regression approaches is correct? (means or raw data).

While I am familiar with the notion that both anova and regression have the same underlying mathematics and are now regarded as general linear modelling, I still don't know how this affects the data that I should be using when running a linear model of the form:  Diet ~ Biomass

Using raw data seems better because it captures the variability in the dataset, but if i use it with Biomass as a continous variable to get a slope value (i.e regression analysis) I am concerned that it inflates the degrees of freedom (df=1,149) and is psuedo-replicated, so inaccurately increases my chances of a significant result? Therefore, is it incorrect to model the raw data (n=150) against only 5 values of "Biomass" in a linear form (and not as factors as required in an anova)?